# When setting up a Xamarin command could I do this in the viewModel class constructor?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application has been code like this but I am not sure if this is correct. In particular "return aButtonClickedCommand ??" which I assume means if the command has not already been defined then create it.

Rather than doing it this way would it be cleaner to just declare the command in the constructor and if so how could I do that and use it?

```
public partial class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ICommand aButtonClickedCommand;

    public ICommand AButtonClickedCommand
    {
       get
       {
           return aButtonClickedCommand ?? (aButtonClickedCommand = 
                  new Command(() => {
                        App.DB.IncrementPoints(Settings.cfs, phrasesFrame.phrase, (int)Settings.aBtn, 1);
                        Change.points = true;
                        phrasesFrame.CancelTimer2();
            }));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You you can do it in the constructor, or another command pattern and may look a little cleaner and also saves putting it in the constructor

```
private ICommand abuttonClickedCommand;

public ICommand AButtonClickedCommand => aButtonClickedCommand ?? (aButtonClickedCommand = new Command(ProcessButtonClickedCommand));

private void ProcessButtonClickedCommand()
{

   App.DB.IncrementPoints(Settings.cfs, phrasesFrame.phrase, (int)Settings.aBtn, 1);
   Change.points = true;
   phrasesFrame.CancelTimer2();

}
```

You are basically correct, if its not created (then create it), however some people like the constructor approach as well